# In MVC, how to pre - load the script to be available in all of the views

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have developed a ASP.NET MVC application with multiple views. I have script Common.js which has a few functions that is used by all the views(in all the views I have included the Common js file)

Now each time I switch from one view to another, the js loads again and takes a lot of time. How to load the js when the application starts and make it available thought the entire application without reloading??

Also can I just create a view and load the JavaScript there and have it available to all the views??

Comment: give your js expiry time. so your js will be saved on browser cache and don't need to load everytime

Comment: You need to call it in your layout.     @Scripts.Render("your script path")

Answer (score 0):

Just render your javascript in your layout so it will automatically render in all pages that uses this layout.
Include this in your page layout.

```
@Scripts.Render("[Your script path here")
```

Comment: But does this not reload the script everytime the view is changed??

Comment: Yes It does load javascript every time the layout call on page.

Comment: But I want the JavaScript to be loaded only once, when the application loads for the first time. Then it should be present throughout the entirety of application